# Building phonegap 1.7. app

Tags: android, cordova

I would like to build an app with existing 1.7 sources.
Since they are created one year ago, I maybe need to migrate the project. Or build the files, as they are.

I don't need to modify anything.

Phonegap 3 does not provide support for 1.7 projects.

Also I can't find any xml, but the Cordova.plist.
And there is no Eclipse project file.

I could use cli of version 1.7.
So here are my questions:
Which commands do I need in cli to build a phonegap 1.7 project?
How to migrate my project to phonegap 3.2.?

Comment: What is your question?
You can't use the CLI to build a 1.7 project. 
You can get the 1.7 files from here: http://archive.apache.org/dist/cordova/
You would need to use the 1.7 workflow to build your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I could use cli of version 1.7.

There isn't a "CLI" per-se for 1.7 but there are shell scripts that you can use to create a project. You have to manually add the plugin code.

> So here are my questions: Which commands do I need in cli to build a
>   phonegap 1.7 project?

You'll need to run the `/bin/create` script for each platform that you want to run the application on. This will create a basic cordova app for you that can be launched onto devices.

> How to migrate my project to phonegap 3.2.?

The best way is to download the latest Cordova from npm and follow the [Command Line Interface Guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.2.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) to build a basic hello world app. Then add the plugins that you need, then copy over your custom HTML code into the new app, build, and test. Yes there are [Upgrade guides](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.2.0/guide_platforms_android_upgrading.md.html#Upgrading%20Android) but when you are jumping from 1.7 to 3.2 it is probably going to be easiest to just build a new app and copy as much code over as you can, rather than following the upgrade guides.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong - but there ain't any `/bin/create` scripts in version 1.7. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Hi @PeterI I think you may be correct. I was thinking `2.7`, not `1.7`. 1.7 is pretty old, and I have not been able to find an actual copy to verify your statement. I would highly recommend against building a 1.7 version - I can't imagine how out of date it must be at this point.

Comment: It is completely useless. You can obtain a copy of 1.7 here: [Link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/zipball/1.7.0)  - but I started creating a new project, just doing all the coding again. xcode changed much, eclipse changed much. It's a lot of work to do. Mobile development is a very fast growing market. If you want to stick with it, you need to update as soon as possible. Not like me ... 1 year after. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking. The cordova project puts out a point release every month. I'd recommend bookmarking their blog or twitter so that you can update the tools and plugins every month, or sooner. You're welcome and good luck!